# Modifying HTML with jQuery from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Trying to learn/develop with jQuery and came across a scenario that I'm not sure how to handle.

I have a HTML table that is being made dynamically by PHP, each row in the table contains a filename and a button to open the file, as of right now the button is calling a JavaScript function that takes in the UNC filepath to that file. I would like to use jQuery to modify the HTML to open the file contents (at this point just trying with .txt files). So my problem is that I need to pass the UNC filepath from the javascript call to the backend through jQuery so I can load the file.

So to visualize it:

HTML:

//Div where I want the file to display

```
<div id="file">
</div>
```

//Each button in the table has a different unc_path_to_file

```
<button onclick="openMedia('unc_path_to_file')">Open</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function openMedia(path){
    //These are not working
    $("file").empty();
    $("file").html("<p>Hello World</p>");
}
```

I can't seem to find any examples online that go this route so I think I'm heading down the wrong path / not understanding something. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use `$("#file").load(url)` to load content from urls. You can't load from the filesystem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `#` character to indicate you are selecting by ID.

```
$("#file").empty();
$("#file").html("<p>Hello World</p>");
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

jQuery won't be able to directly access a UNC path, however you can pass the path to a PHP passthrough script, PHP can then fetch the file for you:

```
$("#file").load("getFile.php?path=" + path);
```

This assumes you have written a `getFile.php` script to get the file you want and return it (careful, you'll want to tightly validate the `path` that you pass in, this could easily be abused).

Comment: This doesn't address the part of the question where he wants to load content from a UNC path.